# Github Actions: Build Failing for NEXT JS PWA App

Tags: github-actions

I have set up Unit tests to be run before pushing to the main branch via GitHub-actions. All the Unit tests are running successfully but for some reason during the build:

```
Ran all test suites.
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
warn  - using beta Middleware (not covered by semver)
```

After this step, it fails with the error:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property.
```

This error comes from the Firebase Admin SDK Configuration file as shown below:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

const keyString = process.env.FB_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY ?? '{"privateKey": ""}';

const { privateKey } = JSON.parse(keyString);

if (privateKey === '') {
  console.log('FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY is not set');
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    throw new Error('FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY is not set');
  else console.log('Firebase Private Key Error');
}

if (admin.apps.length === 0)
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      clientEmail: process.env.FB_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: privateKey,
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID,
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.FB_ADMIN_RTDB_URL,
  });

const db = admin.firestore();
const auth = admin.auth();
const storage = admin.storage();
const rdb = admin.database();

const Server = { auth, db, storage, rdb };
export default Server;
```

However, I am not sure why is this method even called? Since I have my `.env` secrets stored in the local, the build seems to succeed there and fail in Github actions. What should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Since NEXT JS Generates static pages and so I was using Admin SDK to fetch some metadata at the server-side and that's why the function was triggered causing it to fail in Github Actions, seems like the only way out here will be to somehow mock the data in order for the actions to run smoothly.